# Is it possible to specify required LESS version?

Tags: less

Can I specify a LESS compiler version, that is required to compile the file? E.g. in a comment at the beginning of the file:

```
// use 1.5.0
```

I've searched [the docs](http://lesscss.org/), but it seems like there are no such option.

Comment: Are you using a compiler? I would not advise using the javascript compiler on your site, as it will slow down the page rendering. Here is a compiler if you're on a mac: http://incident57.com/less/.

Comment: @Jack does it support specifying version within a file?

Comment: I do not believe so, which is why it was not an answer, but a comment. I don't use that compiler, I use codekit, which is not free, but it does more than just LESS. It (codekit) does not have that option.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to specify?

Comment: @Jack because different versions of the compiler produce different output. If CodeKit doesn't support specifying a version, why to even mention it?

Comment: I understand that, lol. I mean, is there a reason not to just use the most recent one? If you're not using a compiler like codekit, etc, here are the version compilers: https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. Just use the one that you need. If you need multiple, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: I never mention that I need multiple versions, I need to specify a version because another person used an older version of the compiler, which led to unexpected results, still no warning or error was generated.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't meaning to imply that you needed multiple, I was just trying to cover my bases. If you need it to compile a different version, the only thing I know to do is use one of the old files from that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically no, there's no such option. And even if it's added in future LESS versions, an older versions still won't have it so this does not help too much soon. Besides older less.js versions, there're a few LESS ports which are also a bit behind the official implementation so you never know what happens with your LESS sources when you give it away.
(Not mentioning that each LESS compiler also usually has several options that affect CSS output, e.g.: --strict-math).

Well, there's possibility to put a sort of version guard into your code, for example once I tried something like this:

```
.version-guard__() when not(length(-) = 1) {
    -:@@-;@-:': requires LESS version 1.5.0 or higher';
} .version-guard__();
```

But it works in less.js only, and it's not so easy to craft an universal trick that will work with other LESS implementations since each one handles errors in slightly different ways (though, to be honest, I did not bother with that too much since my main goal was to get a reasonable error message).

P.S. Alternative version guard method:

```
.version-guard__ {
    -+: requires LESS version 1.5.0 or higher;
}
```

This one works in less.js and lessphp (at least) but generates dummy CSS output (unlike the first one).